# Restrict ajax calls from outside of node app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I want to restrict AJAX calls other than my application. I don't want my AJAX request to send response when called from outside my application, even when the url of AJAX call is copied and pasted in browser. I am using node, express and mongodb.

Comment: You can check the domain of the request or put in some form of authorization.

Comment: @George Yes, I can surely do that but imagine the scenario where I am just copying the request url and opening it in browser itself, then it will still respond successfully. I want to avoid this as well. "put in some form of authorization" What kind of authentication?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was add some headers in my ajax calls:

```
// javascript
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json", "app-ver": 1.5}
})
.

// php
$client_ver = floatval($_SERVER['HTTP_APP_VER']);

// I also check $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE'] to be: 'application/json'
// and post method. (ask me I'll add)

if ( $client_ver != 1.5 )
{
    echo '{}';
    exit();
}
```

Edit:
Another way would be creating a "session" with your app, meaning every request after a successful login has to carry a token (at least)
and have your app attach lots of unique header key-values that is only recognizable by your server, and not any two requests are a like (eg: include time in header, and hash it with REST command, and have server check it to make sure it's a unique command, and it's not just being manipulated.
* You have to know your session creation algorithm and it HAS to be unique, or if you don't know how to do it, I suggest research more about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but referrer and header spoofing is quite easy to do, how can I avoid that?

Comment: Thanks @Mac. I implemented the same in my app and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs on a user's machine (like a JavaScript web app) then it is impossible to prevent someone from making the calls from outside of your app.  You can make it harder by using a nonce with each request, but even then someone could build their own app that mimics your app and makes the calls in the correct order.

In short: you can't ever fully trust the client and you can't prevent someone from spoofing the client.  You need to re-examine your requirements.

Comment: hi *Brandon*/comunity, please: what means *... using a nonce...*, I search iun GOOGLE and nothing as answer, regards.

Comment: hey @Stackoverflow here you can find about *NONCE*: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Cryptographic+nonce